# As a Admin of App Update the Email of Login User in Flutter using FireStore

Tags: flutter, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update the email and name of users as i have list of users so how to update the authentication email also and then user login with the updates email that i have updated

```
ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Update'),
              onPressed: () {
                final newName = nameController.text;
                final newEmail = emailController.text;

                userController.updateUser(userId, newName, newEmail);
// put login for Authenticated email that should be then the newEmail

              },
```

Comment: Please edit your question as per the [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are looking for updating user profiles then you can follow these docs on [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users)

Comment: HI does that comment help ? If not then Please provide more information about what you want to achieve.